# Qt/Qml How to lock variable , sql for multi operation at same time

Tags: multithreading, qt, qml, qthread

I have an class(worker.cpp) that extends from QThread.This thread emit servercheck signal to MobileOperation.cpp(onservercheck metod) every 60 second.That OK. 
I have an button in qml screen.This button invoke a metod in MobileOperation.cpp(postworkaccept). 
Common point of two job is using m_user->teamId to make request to server.
My problem is, if I click button in qml to invoke postworkaccept metod  at the same time with worker thread, then app is crash.How to prevent for crashing app in QT/QML

Comment: You don't need to extend `QThread`. Instead, make the worker a `QObject`, then move it to the worker thread. The object can have a slot that does the work. You can connect to that slot from QML.

Comment: @KubaOber , worker.cpp must control server every 60 second like bacground process.Can Qmutex be used for this problem.